# Please blacklist [best-practices]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-blacklist

[best-practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) was recently burninated and removed from all 700+ questions that had it. However, it's sprung up again like wild fire on 6 new questions in the last week.

Can this tag be blacklisted, so it doesn't keep coming back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike [this cat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bETCusT5kNM), this tag will not come back the very next day.