# Why is Best-Practices Tags black listed?

Tags: support, tags, tag-blacklist

Referring to this:

[Please blacklist [best-practices]](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/please-blacklist-best-practices)

Why is tags [best practices] tag blacklisted anyway? Does it define any ambiguity or does it cater to poor quality answers? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: -1? Was this a very offensive act to ask something? This was just a curiosity. I don't really care about down votes and i don't even know what my rep on meta is. But why down vote? What is in appropriate here?

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences), and [there's no rep](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) - Also, voting is not used to denote offensive questions on Meta or the main site, if your question was somehow offensive (it's not) people would flag it as such.

Comment: @YannisRizos Good. Thanks. But was there anything wrong about this question?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, someone probably didn't find your question interesting / helpful. Don't get stuck on a single downvote, on Meta or the main site...

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Let's nuke the catch-all tags](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/should-we-nuke-the-catch-all-tags)

It's a tag that could theoretically be added to every question on the site. If you think about it all questions are ultimately asking for the "best" way to do something.

Comment: Also "[The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)", where [tag:best-practices] is explicitly called out.